# Ajax it does nothing when sending parameters to a php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am a beginner using ajax and am trying to change the status of reading a book by clicking an image.
I had the code working but without ajax. Now I have no php error but not a change in mysql.
The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendState(state_id){
        var hd_haveread = $("#hd_haveread").val();
        var hd_toread = $("#hd_toread").val();
        var hd_reading = $("#hd_reading").val();

        var val = 0;
        var baseurl = "img/";

        switch(state_id){
            case 1:
                if (hd_haveread == "0"){
                    document.getElementById('hd_haveread').value = "1";
                    document.getElementById('hd_toread').value = "0";
                    document.getElementById('hd_reading').value = "0";
                    val = 1;
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById('hd_haveread').value = "0";
                    val = 0;
                }
            break;
            case 3:
                if (hd_toread == "0"){
                    document.getElementById('hd_toread').value = "1";
                    document.getElementById('hd_haveread').value = "0";
                    document.getElementById('hd_reading').value = "0";
                    val = 1;
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById('hd_toread').value = "0";
                    val = 0;
                }
            break;
            case 2:
                if (hd_reading == "0"){
                    document.getElementById('hd_reading').value = "1";
                    document.getElementById('hd_haveread').value = "0";
                    document.getElementById('hd_toread').value = "0";
                    val = 1;
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById('hd_reading').value = "0";
                    val = 0;
                }
            break;
        }

        var parameters = {
            "book" : <?php echo $id_book; ?>,
            "state" : state_id,
            "val" : val
        };
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            data:  parameters,
            url:   'change_state_ajax.php',
            type:  'post',
            dataType: "html",
            beforeSend: function (){
            },
            success: function (response){
                switch(state_id){
                    case 1:
                        if (hd_haveread == "0"){
                            $("#img_haveread1").css("display","none");
                            $("#img_haveread2").css("display","inline-block");
                            $("#img_toread1").css("display","inline-block");
                            $("#img_toread2").css("display","none");
                            $("#img_reading1").css("display","inline-block");
                            $("#img_reading2").css("display","none");
                        }
                        else{
                            $("#img_haveread1").css("display","inline-block");
                            $("#img_haveread2").css("display","none");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 3:
                        if (hd_toread == "0"){
                            $("#img_haveread1").css("display","inline-block");
                            $("#img_haveread2").css("display","none");
                            $("#img_toread1").css("display","none");
                            $("#img_toread2").css("display","inline-block");
                            $("#img_reading1").css("display","inline-block");
                            $("#img_reading2").css("display","none");
                        }
                        else{
                            $("#img_toread1").css("display","inline-block");
                            $("#img_toread2").css("display","none");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 2:
                        if (hd_reading == "0"){
                            $("#img_haveread1").css("display","inline-block");
                            $("#img_haveread2").css("display","none");
                            $("#img_toread1").css("display","inline-block");
                            $("#img_toread2").css("display","none");
                            $("#img_reading1").css("display","none");
                            $("#img_reading2").css("display","inline-block");
                        }
                        else{
                            $("#img_reading1").css("display","inline-block");
                            $("#img_reading2").css("display","none");
                        }
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

And the change_state_ajax.php code:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['book']) && isset($_POST['state']) && isset($_POST['val'])){
        include 'connection.php';
        include('php_lib/config.ini.php');
        include_once('php_lib/login.lib.php');

        $lib_id = $_POST['book'];
        $state = $_POST['state'];
        $val = $_POST['val'];

        $result=changeState($lib_id, $state, $val); 
        echo $result;
    }

    function changeState($lib_id, $state, $val){
        session_start();
        $usu_id = $_SESSION['USSER']['id'];
        $mark = 0;
        $pos = 0;

        $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT uliusu_id, ulilib_id, uliedl_id FROM '.TABLE_USSERS_BOOKS.' WHERE ulilib_id = :fil_lib_id AND uliusu_id = :fil_usu_id');
        $query->bindParam(':fil_lib_id', $lib_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->bindParam(':fil_usu_id', $usu_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->execute();

        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
            $mark = 1;
            $state_actual = $row->uliedl_id;
        }

        if($mark == 0){
            $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO '.TABLE_USSERS_BOOKS.' (uliusu_id, ulilib_id, uliedl_id, uli_posicion, uli_fecha) VALUES (:fil_usu_id, :fil_lib_id, :fil_edl_id, :fil_pos, NOW())');
            $query->bindParam(':fil_usu_id', $usu_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->bindParam(':fil_lib_id', $lib_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->bindParam(':fil_edl_id', $state, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->bindParam(':fil_pos', $pos, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->execute();
        }else{
            if($state == $state_actual){
                $query = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM '.TABLE_USSERS_BOOKS.' WHERE ulilib_id = :fil_lib_id AND uliusu_id = :fil_usu_id');
                $query->bindParam(':fil_usu_id', $usu_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $queryquery->bindParam(':fil_lib_id', $lib_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $query->execute();
            }else{
                $query = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE '.TABLE_USSERS_BOOKS.' SET uliedl_id = :fil_edl_id WHERE ulilib_id = :fil_lib_id AND uliusu_id = :fil_usu_id');
                $query->bindParam(':fil_edl_id', $state, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $query->bindParam(':fil_usu_id', $usu_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $query->bindParam(':fil_lib_id', $lib_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $query->execute();
            }
        }

        if($state == 1){
            $result = 0;
        }else{
            $result = 1;
        }

        return $result;
    }
?>
```

Can anyone help me solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Where specifically does it fail?  Is the AJAX request sent?  Does it have the expected values?  Step through client-side and server-side code in a debugger and narrow down the problem.

Comment: You are POSTing the data but looking in $_GET to fetch it :)

Comment: When I debug the ajax do nothing and passes without any errors.
I tried all variants with "get" and "post" and the only that has changed the "display" was this. With post in both sides it gives me "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: Can you call your PHP script directly in the browser by passing GET variables in the URL?

Comment: typo error `"estado"`  to `"state"`

Comment: I checked it, there must be a problem with your `"include" files` or the `mysql query error`. Add this on the top of your php script `ini_set("display_errors",1);` this will help you to detect error. Also wrap your mysql part within `try{... }catch(PDOException $e){
 echo $e->getMessage();
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not checking for the proper variables. Your JavaScript passes a var called `estado` but you check in PHP for a var called `state`.

And because you require all three variables to be set your condition fails.

Also like Hank said in his comment your `jQuery.Ajax` call uses POST (`type: 'post',`) but then in your PHP script you check `GET` variables which of course are not set.

Either change you jQuery call type to `GET` or change the checking in your PHP script to `POST`

```
if(isset($_POST['book']) && isset($_POST['state']) && isset($_POST['val'])){
    include 'connection.php';
    include('php_lib/config.ini.php');
    include_once('php_lib/login.lib.php');

    $lib_id = $_POST['book'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $val = $_POST['val'];

    $result=changeState($lib_id, $state, $val); 
    echo $result;
}
```

Comment: sorry, this was because of the translation I did for you can see it better. The var is called estado in my code.
I tried with post and the new error is:
POST http://localhost/MisBooks6/cambiar_estado_ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Thanks a lot Sébastien! I found the error in that way. the error was in the php code, I could not see it because ajax was hiding it

Comment: Sure thing, happens all the time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Things I noticed:

1) First you are POSTing but in PHP, you are using $_GET.

2) you are passing "book", "estado", "val" but are trying to get "book", "state", "val", so it never enters into if condition

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry, this was because of the translation I did for you can see it better. The var is called estado in my code.
The error was in the php code, I could not see it because ajax was hiding it